# Clarification on dynamic memory

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have the following piece of code:

```
int *q = new int(42), *r = new int(100);
r = q;
```

`r` will now point to the same dynamically allocated object as `q`. What happens to the object that was created during the initialization of `r`? Is it still valid? How do you `delete` it?

I know that writing:

```
delete q;
```

will invalidate both q and r. If I did:

```
delete r;
```

won't this invalidate both q and r also?

And even if it did wouldn't the original `int` object with value 100 still be hanging around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What happens to the object that was created during the initialization of `r`?

Nothing.

> Is it still valid?

Yes.

> How do you `delete` it?

You can't. You just lost the only pointer to it. It will lurk in the background for the rest of the program's lifetime (and even beyond, on some primitive operating systems). This is known as a *memory leak*.

This is one of many good reasons not to use raw pointers to manage resources. If you used smart pointers, there would be no leak. It's also a good reason to avoid `new` unless you actually need dynamic allocation.

> won't this invalidate both `q` and `r` also?

Yes. Deleting an object invalidates all pointers to it. This is another good reason not to use raw pointers: there is no way to tell that they've been invalidated.

Comment: Actually, in his specific example, is there any reason to use pointers and dynamic memory at all?  In a real life example, whether to use a smart pointer or not depends on a lot of things; you can't make any dogmatic statement to the effect "don't use raw pointers", because raw pointers are appropriate more often than not.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Indeed, I should probably add "don't use `new` unless you mean it", but I don't want to turn this into too much of a lecture. And I didn't make a dogmatic statement of "don't use raw pointers"; I just pointed out two good reasons to avoid them, especially for resource management (which, incidentally, is something I *am* dogmatic about - at least in C++11, there's never a good reason not to use RAII).

Comment: @JamesKanze Raw pointers are necessary in C, but it's almost impossible to justify if you're working with C++11.  (There are some exceptions, but it almost always means you're doing it wrong)

Comment: @MikeSeymour RAII works _when_ the need for the resources corresponds to a block.  In such cases, it's excellent, but if the need for an object (and its memory) corresponds to a block, then there's no need for dynamic allocation (usually---there are exceptions).  That's my whole point: when smart pointers solve the problem, you usually shouldn't be allocating dynamically to begin with.

Comment: @IronSavior That's simply wrong.  In well written C++, most pointers will be for navigation, and for those, raw pointers are the most appropriate.  (And of course, in C++, you can't avoid raw pointers.  The language simply doesn't allow it.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: RAII, with move semantics, also works when you need to transfer ownership from one scope to another - which is precisely when you need dynamic allocation. So I maintain my opinion that one should *always* use RAII to manage dynamic objects. (Of course, I'm not suggesting that one use it instead of automatic storage, in case I gave that impression).

Comment: @IronSavior: Raw pointers *for resource management* are unjustifiable in C++11; but they have plenty of other uses, as long as you're careful not to invalidate them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Move semantics can help; I don't know if I would consider that RAII, but it's pretty close.  But in a lot of cases involving objects, even move semantics aren't appropriate.  The object will be created in one transaction, then hang around until another transaction deletes it.  With hundreds or thousands of transactions in the meantime.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I was using RAII fairly loosely to mean "a thing that manages another thing's lifetime", not a strictly scope-bound object. I don't see how your transactions require raw pointers rather than unique pointers.

Comment: @MikeSeymour And I think we're actually agreeing.  My only point is that it is fairly rare for pointers to be used for resource management.  (And that the observer pattern gets a heavy workout in applications which do dynamic allocation.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour Because the moment an object should disappear is controlled by a request, which is processed by a transaction.  The object isn't managed by any pointers, anywhere.  It's managed by the program logic, responding to requests.  (There are, of course, cases where you would use a pointer for resource management, but only at a very low level---implementing a smart pointer, for example, or something like `std::vector` or a tree like `std::map`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: OK, so you're describing a system that doesn't use any kind of pointer to manage resources; which is entirely compatible with my view that one shouldn't use raw pointers to manage resources. (Perhaps I should have simply repeated "don't use raw pointers" instead of introducing the concept of RAII, since I guess not everyone would regard a self-managing object as RAII. Sorry for the confusion I caused.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour I was talking about resource management.  This question is about dynamic memory management, so I figured that was implicit.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your questions are:

1. You cannot delete that object now as you are not referring to it in anyway, thus causing a memory leak.(try using smart pointers)
2. You cannot delete the object unless you have a pointer referring to it.
3. Deleting an object invalidates all the pointers pointing to that object.

Answer (score 1):

This assignment will cause a memory leak:

```
r = q;
```

the memory pointed to by `r` previously is still valid but you no longer have a pointer to it and can not `delete` it. Calling `delete` on `q` or `r` at this point will invalidate both.